# Kurento Java tutorial helloworld stuck during start

Tags: kurento

I try to run Kurento HelloWorld with

```
mvn exec:java
```

but it always stay here for a long time(several minutes) before the start going on. What operation is going at this point?

```
exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ kurento-hello-world ---
   .------------------------------------.
   |                                    |
   |   | |/ /  _ _ _ ___ _ _| |_ ___    |
   |   | ' 


       Kurento Java Tutorial - Hello World
       Version 6.2.1


16:26:58.684 [HelloWorldApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.helloworld.HelloWorldApp    - Starting HelloWorldApp on instance-c5pf3tu2 with PID 14998 (/home/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world/target/classes started by root in /home/kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world)
16:26:58.695 [HelloWorldApp.main()] DEBUG - o.k.tutorial.helloworld.HelloWorldApp    - Running with Spring Boot v1.3.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.3.RELEASE
16:26:58.695 [HelloWorldApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.helloworld.HelloWorldApp    - No profiles are active
16:26:59.768 [     pool-1-thread-1] INFO  - o.h.validator.internal.util.Version      - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps :

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.2.0
mvn compile exec:java
```

Hope it work for you

Comment: Thank you. I followed your step to checkout 6.2.0, but I got compile error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (default) on project kurento-hello-world: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: bower installed in your system??

Comment: @SantoshShingare I compiled  and i am able to access the url.but the remote streamm not showing

Comment: @SantoshShingare  bower installed and Tutorial 6.2.1 compiled successfully, but 6.2.0 comiled with error. I wonder why it takes serveral minutes to start. Afer the helloword started, the remote stream  also takes long time to show, and it lag so much. Maybe the same reason caused the very slow startup and very laggard remote stream.

Comment: @elon-li Error with 6.2.0, because `java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/keystore.jks (No such file or directory) `, you have to create keystore.jks then it will run. Can you tell me what is your network structure, If it running on same system (Client and KMS)  it should be very smooth(without any delay).

Comment: @Shijin can you show your log. If your server is running, and client is connected to kurento, it  will load page.

Comment: @SantoshShingare video calling is not working,loopback example and one to many is working

Comment: @SantoshShingare Tutorial Application and KMS are both running on one same server .